# How to reformat this date in excel

Tags: excel

[image]

How do I reformat this to yy/mm/dd in excel? text to column doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Select the range, right click, format cells, select custom, type: "yy/mm/dd".

[image]

Comment: @Sillyone If it works then please mark the answer as accepted (tick mark it).

Answer (score 0):

Text dates are not date values.
You should convert the text to date values first.

You can use `=DATEVALUE(text)` to get the date value from the text date.

However, the weekday should not be in the text. `DATEVALUE` function does not accept it. So, you have to trim that first.

For example, find the first "," and drop out that with additional two letters.

```
=DATEVALUE(MID(A1,FIND(",",A1)+2,LEN(A1)))
```

And, you have to format the date cell to `yy/mm/dd`.
Then, the result should be like this
[image]

Comment: Thanks! now i have a new problem.... when i change those dates to yy/mm/dd format and save the csv they revert back to mm/dd/yy and I can not import that into MySql. How to do i save the file without the dates reverting back to the old format.

Comment: @Sillyone Then you can convert it using `YEAR()`, `MONTH()`, and `DAY()` like `=YEAR(B1)&"/"&MONTH(B1)&"/"&DAY(B1)`.

Comment: @Sillyone I would keep the 4-digit year, so use yyyy. If you want MySql dates, they should be in the format yyyy-mm-dd. Excel has a terrible habit of trying to be helpful with dates, and will often convert automatically when you re-open the CSV. Open your .csv files using Notepad, which will show you what you actually have in the file. Once you have your date in Excel, use =TEXT(dt,"'yyyy-mm-dd'") to convert it into a string enclosed in single quotes ('). Excel wont try and convert that, and MySql should be able to interpret it.